# Action Script 3 позиция на экране

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Добрый день.

Делается приложение на AS3 (без adobe air !).
У данного приложения достаточно большая протяжённость по вертикали (2000+ px). Таким образом в браузере оно показывается со скроллингом.
Приложение отображает длинный список, щёлкнув по элементу которого открывается всплывающее окно (в этом же приложении, средствами AS3).

Вопрос:
Как задать всплывающему окну координату "y" c учётом прокрутки экрана - т.е. всегда посередине окошка браузера? Я бы хотел получить, например, координату окна браузера относительно приложения, тогда можно было бы посчитать нужную позицию, но я не знаю, как. :(

p.s.: Сейчас у меня координаты всплывающего окна привязаны к координатам элемента списка, но такой вариант пока оставляет желать лучшего.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если флешка и сайт ваши - можно запользовать ExternalInterface и с помощью javascript получить нужные данные и передать во флеш.

Как получить значение прокрутки - это вопрос уже по другой теме и, в принципе, легко гуглится=)

Comment: Да, у меня это приложение вконтакте - у вконтакте API есть для этого инструменты. Через него я и сделал то, что мне нужно.

Ну, как я понимаю средствами только флеш этого не сделать? Думаю, я получил ответ на свой вопрос :)

Comment: Ввиду специфичности задачи (кто их знает, в какой браузер запихают флешку и как там эти сведения получать ^^") - не думаю, что создатели платформы реализовывали такой функционал =3

Answer (score 1):

кошерный вариант - убрать скролл внутрь флешки, тогда не надо будет следить за скролом в браузере, плюс можно отвязаться от внешнего контекста (на случай запуска флешки вне браузера), кстати часть браузеров не скролят колесиком, если фокус на флешке (что по моему имху жуткий минус :) )

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле, описано крайне непонятно. Из того, что написано, я понял, что проблема со скролом браузера.

Я бы либо, скоратил размер флэша до 600px и делал обработку внутри flash container. Тогда скрол как угодно можно программировать.

Либо есть вариант, делать js калбеки и получать и менять нужные данные. Но это хуже, так как разные браузеры по разному их обрабатывают. И часто на этом варианте происходят глюки, задержки и т.д.

Comment: Вы немножко запоздали с ответом :) Да и тот, что есть, повторяет существующие